# Connection issues with mongodb. Half of my inserts fail with multiple errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, electron

I have my nodejs electron application that is trying to insert records into mongodb.
Half of the attempts fail, only way I have managed to use it is by putting insert request into loop and trying until it succeeds. If I need to insert 10 records, I might need 20-30 attempts.
I have tried with the regular mongodb library and with mongoose client as well, both with the same issue. Here are some of the errors I get while trying my insert.

> Failed inserting record to mongoDB MongoWaitQueueTimeoutError: Timed out while checking out a connection from connection pool

> Failed inserting record to mongoDB MongoPoolClearedError: Connection pool for x.x.x.x:27777 was cleared because another operation failed with: "connection  to x.x.x.x:27777 timed out"

> Failed inserting record to mongoDB MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection 3 to x.x.x.x:27777 timed out

> Failed inserting record to mongoDB PoolClearedOnNetworkError: Connection to x.x.x.x:27777 interrupted due to server monitor timeout

I'm connecting with default settings. Have tried mongo version from docker or installing directly on my server. It seems that it might be related to it being used from electron, as I have never had this problem from a regular nodejs running on the server.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you aren't releasing connections back to the pool when you should be. So it's trying to make too many connections and waiting in a queue... Could you add some code to demonstrate how you are using it? Also you should be able to use an individual connection and do all 10 requests (for example) and then release that connection back to the pool.

Comment: That is what I thought at first. But I made sure that I have only one connection when I initialise. But I'm not releasing it when electron exits. Won't it be released when I end the process/app ?

Comment: Yeah I think that the connection will expire on it's own... Are you sure you are only using one connection? It appears whatever package you are using, it's using a pool in the background or something... Also it appears that the connection is timing out as well... Which would indicate that the connection is expiring (which could be the initial chain problem)... Could you create a minimal reproducible example?